# How do I get statistics on HTTP traffic from Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-analyzer, graph

I have captured traffic with `dumpcap` and filtered http only with Wireshark.

I want to see statistics about that http traffic. For example: requests grouped by method and URL, ordered by number of occurrences, etc. Then, I would like to graph the group sizes on a PIE chart.

How do I that? What tools do I use?

Comment: Why did you rate me down -1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save filtered traffic with Wireshark 1.10?](http://serverfault.com/questions/625317/how-do-i-save-filtered-traffic-with-wireshark-1-10)

Comment: Please read carefully. This question is about grouping traffic and charting the groups. The one you pointed to is about saving filtered traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Menu Statistic ->HTTP -> packet Counter/Requests/Load Distri ...
or use a filter when you run wireshark for sniffing http traffic :
in the filter bar :
http. 
one list apparea for all options for HTTP

or

menu statistic -> Flow Graph for see conversation

or use python scapy library for that is very powerfull